# Decrypt string using Python M2Crypto

Tags: python, m2crypto

I am trying to decrypt an email message in python using M2Crypto.  The problem I have is the examples I find online all seem to read in a file.  But in my code I have a string that contains the body of an email.  So I am passing in the body of the email.

Here is the code I am basing my program from:

`from M2Crypto import BIO, SMIME, X509`

```
def decryptMessage(body):
  # Instantiate an SMIME object.
  s = SMIME.SMIME()

  # Load private key and cert.
  s.load_key('recipient_key.pem', 'recipient.pem')

  # Load the encrypted data.
  p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7(body)

  # Decrypt p7.
  out = s.decrypt(p7)

  return out.read()
```

When I do this, I get an error that says "File name too long"

Can someone help me understand how to decrypt a string from my email?

Answer (score 0):

smime_load_pkcs7 takes a file name as it's argument so it is interpreting the body of the email, which you are passing, as the file name. The SMIME library is unfortunately poorly documented and it isn't clear if there is a variant that takes a string as an argument instead of a file. One hack around this would be something like:

```
f = open("tmp", 'w')
f.write(body)
p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7("tmp") 
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have access to the file system like that.  Hence the reason my message in in a local variable. :D